# EntitySpaces error "The type 'BusinessObjects.LeadInfoCore' is not mapped as a Table."

Tags: c#, sql, database, asp.net-mvc-4, entityspaces

I am brand new to EntitySpaces and have been using SubSonic for quite some time now. I am just getting started with a project and was told to use EntitySpaces and am getting an error "The type 'BusinessObjects.LeadInfoCore' is not mapped as a Table." from the following code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult SkyNet()
        {
            // Target the table we want to query
            LeadInfoCoreCollection coll = new LeadInfoCoreCollection();
            // re-opens the data connection to SQL      
            DataContext coo = new DataContext(coll.es.Connection.ConnectionString);

            var query = coo.GetTable<LeadInfoCore>().Where(s => s.AdvertiserId != null).Take(50);

            return View();
        }
    }
```

The error is occurring on the "var query = coo.GetTable...." line. I followed the instructions and pretty much copied the example from the API help file. I have looked everywhere for help on this and it just doesn't really seem to have happened to anyone else. The connection to the db works just fine as I tested it by querying a single entry from the db with the LoadByPrimaryKey() function.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead, it appears you are trying to use EntitySpaces mixed with EF, It's not meant to work that way, but if you want to use the EntitySpaces dynamic query against your database to load your EF data model classes this is the way to go ...

http://brewdawg.github.io/Tiraggo.EF/

Querying databases with linq is horrible and terrible limited and slow compared to Tiraggo.EF which has the same API as EntitySpaces.